# Printing From JSON Without Key Name

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing

I'm getting a JSON output from the VirusTotal API, as seen below:

```
{
    "scan_id": "id_goes_here",
    "resource": "domain_goes_here",
    "url": "http://example.com/",
    "response_code": 1,
    "scan_date": "2021-01-19 21:28:32",
    "permalink": "https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/id_goes_here/detection/u-id_goes_here",
    "verbose_msg": "Scan finished, scan information embedded in this object",
    "filescan_id": null,
    "positives": 0,
    "total": 83,
    "scans": {
        "CMC Threat Intelligence": {
            "detected": false,
            "result": "clean site"
        },
        "CLEAN MX": {
            "detected": false,
            "result": "clean site"
        },
        "DNS8": {
            "detected": false,
            "result": "clean site"
        },
        "MalwareDomainList": {
            "detected": false,
            "result": "clean site",
            "detail": "http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/mdl.php?search=example.com"
...
```

I want to go through this JSON and find the entries that have `detected` as `true` and if so print the name. As well, print the reference (if there is one)

For example, let's say the entry for `MalwareDomainList` had `detected` set to `true`. So as below:

```
        "MalwareDomainList": {
            "detected": true,
            "result": "malicious site",
            "detail": "http://www.malwaredomainlist.com/mdl.php?search=example.com"
```

I want to print the name of the list, so in this case, `MalwareDomainList` and also print the value of `detail`. As you can see in the above output, not all lists have a `detail` field.

In python3, I am thinking I need to have something like:

```
scan_content = json.dumps(response.json(), indent =4 )
for scan in scan_content["scans"]:
    if scan["detected"]:
        print("Name of blacklist:", scan["name"])
```

But getting an error since `name` is not an actual key in the output. Not sure how to alter my above code to achieve the following:
If `detected` is set to `true`

1. Print the name of the list
2. If applicable, print value in the `detail` key

Trying the below solution as such:

```
I have the following:

json_data = json.dumps(response.json(), indent =4 )
scan_content = json_data["scans"]
positive = []
for elem in scan_content.keys():
        if  scan_content[elem]["detected"] == "true":
            positive.append({"Name" : elem, "Detail" : scan_content[elem]["detail"]})
print(*positive)
```

I get the error

```
    scan_content = json_data["scans"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: You can use `json.keys()` to get all the keys, then iterate over each key with and check if `key["detected"] == True`

Comment: My issue is that the name of the list does not have a key. So how would I then reference the name if there is no key?

Comment: also you dont need to convert `response.json()` to json object again.